# how to change csv file in different format using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have one CSV file in which one row have lots of value which have been separated by comma. 
I want to separate them into different rows.
Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
Product_name       brand_strength 
STELARA            90MG,130MG,45MG,5MG/1ML
```

Desired Output:

```
Product_name      brand_strength
STELARA           90MG
STELARA           130MG
STELARA           45MG
STELARA           5MG/1ML
```

Comment: What is the separator between the values in the csv? e.g between "STELARA" and "90MG..."

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows), if you are using pandas version >= 25 ,use `pandas.DataFrame.explode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Split your data first and stack them to rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Product_name": ["STELARA"],
                  "brand_strength": ["90MG,130MG,45MG,5MG/1ML"]})

df["brand_strength"] = df["brand_strength"].str.split(",")

df = (df
 .set_index(["Product_name"])['brand_strength']
 .apply(pd.Series)
 .stack()
 .reset_index()
 .drop('level_1', axis=1)
 .rename(columns={0:'brand_strength'}))
```

output :

```
    Product_name   brand_strength
0   STELARA        90MG
1   STELARA        130MG
2   STELARA        45MG
3   STELARA        5MG/1ML
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make changes to your CSV and then write those to a new CSV file.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('<your csv file path'>')

df.assign(brand_strength=df['brand_strength'].str.split(',')).explode('brand_strength')

df.to_csv('<new file name/path>')
```